# docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:

Tags: sockets, docker

I tried this

```
docker run --rm -it -p 2181:2181 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9092:9092 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 landoop/fast-data-dev
```

I got error

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

I have checked if daemon is running

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since уто 2018-01-23 10:52:50 CET; 2h 14min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 11082 (dockerd)
```

This is my /etc/default/docker

```
# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKERD="/usr/local/bin/dockerd"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
#DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export DOCKER_TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

How to edit docker_opts to solve the problem I have?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding your user to the `docker` group:

- Run `usermod -aG docker "${USER}"`, then
- either log out and log back in, or run `newgrp docker`.

After this you have to restart your docker daemon: `sudo service docker restart`.

Comment: It does not help,shpuld I change $USER with my user name?

Comment: you can try but normally ${USER} is replace by your name automaticaly

Comment: And maybe restart your daemon after this.

Comment: Works after restart.

Comment: the command is `systemctl start docker.service` in Arch and CentOS

Comment: Group membership i activated if you log out and back in. In order to activate a group in the current session, you can run `newgrp docker`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent command for Mac? I do not have usermod

Comment: @YuChen check this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-on-command-line

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on an Azure virtual machine or similar, try running the Docker command with `sudo`, e.g.:

```
sudo tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh CPU bazel test //tensorflow/...
```